# Find distance for every edge and keep separate routes

Tags: python, list, dictionary, edges

```
[[0, 100, 7, 27, 34, 40, 41, 48, 58, 65, 75, 78, 79, 96, 126, 127, 0],
[0, 2, 45, 54, 56, 57, 59, 66, 67, 82, 86, 102, 124, 133, 0],
[0, 35, 39, 52, 53, 60, 61, 80, 81, 83, 87, 97, 98, 101, 109, 0],
[0, 15, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 37, 38, 49, 50, 51, 71, 95, 0],
[0, 3, 16, 22, 23, 44, 72, 73, 74, 90, 110, 131, 0],
[0, 10, 11, 18, 19, 36, 55, 89, 93, 94, 108, 113, 114, 0],
[0, 1, 5, 6, 9, 12, 17, 24, 43, 64, 77, 85, 88, 91, 92, 111, 112, 130, 0],
[0, 13, 20, 42, 62, 68, 84, 99, 104, 116, 119, 125, 128, 129, 132, 0],
[0, 8, 14, 26, 63, 69, 70, 103, 105, 123, 0],
[0, 4, 21, 25, 46, 47, 106, 107, 115, 117, 118, 120, 121, 122, 0],
[0, 76, 0]]
```

I have the different routes listed above. I need to calculate the distance of every route (11 routes in total)

After this, I have created all edges within a single route.

[[(0, 100),
  (100, 7),
  (7, 27),
  (27, 34),
  (34, 40),
  (40, 41),
  (41, 48),
  (48, 58),
  (58, 65),
  (65, 75),
  (75, 78),
  (78, 79),
  (79, 96),
  (96, 126),
  (126, 127),
  (127, 0)],
 [(0, 2),
  (2, 45),
  (45, 54),
  (54, 56),
  (56, 57),
  (57, 59),
  (59, 66),
  (66, 67),
  (67, 82),
  (82, 86),
  (86, 102),
  (102, 124),
  (124, 133),
  (133, 0)],
 [(0, 35),
  (35, 39),
  (39, 52),
  (52, 53),
  (53, 60),
  (60, 61),
  (61, 80),
  (80, 81),
  (81, 83),
  (83, 87),
  (87, 97),
  (97, 98),
  (98, 101),
  (101, 109),
  (109, 0)],
 [(0, 15),
  (15, 28),
  (28, 29),
  (29, 30),
  (30, 31),
  (31, 32),
  (32, 33),
  (33, 37),
  (37, 38),
  (38, 49),
  (49, 50),
  (50, 51),
  (51, 71),
  (71, 95),
  (95, 0)],
 [(0, 3),
  (3, 16),
  (16, 22),
  (22, 23),
  (23, 44),
  (44, 72),
  (72, 73),
  (73, 74),
  (74, 90),
  (90, 110),
  (110, 131),
  (131, 0)],
 [(0, 10),
  (10, 11),
  (11, 18),
  (18, 19),
  (19, 36),
  (36, 55),
  (55, 89),
  (89, 93),
  (93, 94),
  (94, 108),
  (108, 113),
  (113, 114),
  (114, 0)],
 [(0, 1),
  (1, 5),
  (5, 6),
  (6, 9),
  (9, 12),
  (12, 17),
  (17, 24),
  (24, 43),
  (43, 64),
  (64, 77),
  (77, 85),
  (85, 88),
  (88, 91),
  (91, 92),
  (92, 111),
  (111, 112),
  (112, 130),
  (130, 0)],
 [(0, 13),
  (13, 20),
  (20, 42),
  (42, 62),
  (62, 68),
  (68, 84),
  (84, 99),
  (99, 104),
  (104, 116),
  (116, 119),
  (119, 125),
  (125, 128),
  (128, 129),
  (129, 132),
  (132, 0)],
 [(0, 8),
  (8, 14),
  (14, 26),
  (26, 63),
  (63, 69),
  (69, 70),
  (70, 103),
  (103, 105),
  (105, 123),
  (123, 0)],
 [(0, 4),
  (4, 21),
  (21, 25),
  (25, 46),
  (46, 47),
  (47, 106),
  (106, 107),
  (107, 115),
  (115, 117),
  (117, 118),
  (118, 120),
  (120, 121),
  (121, 122),
  (122, 0)],
 [(0, 76), (76, 0)]]

However, I need to calculate the distance between the edges. Every edge consists of 2 numbers which are city numbers in a distance matrix (so 0,100 is the distance from city 0 to city 100). I tried to calculate the distances but cannot keep separate routes.

I already tried this:

```
a_list=[]
visiting_time={}
for k in range(len(result)):
    for (i,j) in visits[k]:
        visiting_time[(i,j)]= distance_matrix_new_time[i][j]
        f=list(visiting_time.values())
    a_list.append(f)
```

In my code Result is the list with different routes (first list), and visits is the list with all edges (second list)

the output should be like this

[2,3,5,6,3,2,5,8,3,5,2,4,6],[2,6,3,1,9,....],[....] etc.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use a list comprehension:

```
a_list = [[distance_matrix_new_time[i][j] for i, j in l] for l in  visits]
```